# Cron Job not appearing in the cron list of WP-Control plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron, jobs

Im trying to setup a cron job for all my clients to update their stocks. I've looked into [Cron job in WordPress not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752854/cron-job-in-wordpress-not-working) and [cron job in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676513/cron-job-in-wordpress) but cant get it to appear in the cron list(WP-Control).

im using this:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'cron_add_everyday');
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_add_everyday' );

function cron_add_everyday( $schedules ) {

   $schedules = array('everyday' => array( 'interval' => 86400*1,
                                           'display' => __( 'Every Day')),);
   return $schedules;
}
```

Im using this just to test if i can get it to appear in the list. am i missing something? thanks

Comment: I very much doubt that the `plugins_loaded` action would call your function with any sensible value for `$schedules` …

Comment: it works for other actions, but ive change it to 'wp' and still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so i got it. Full Code:

```
//CUSTOM TIMER 15 minuts, you can change for your won
function myprefix_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
   $schedules['15Minuts'] = array(
                                  'interval' => 900, // 15 minuts in secounds
                                  'display'  => __( '15 minuts' ),
                                   );
   return $schedules;
}
//ADD it
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myprefix_custom_cron_schedule' );

//Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'Your_Function_Hook' ) ) {
       wp_schedule_event( time(), '15Minuts', 'Your_Function_Hook' );
  }

///Hook into that action that'll fire every 15 minuts
add_action( 'Your_Function_Hook', 'Your_Function' );

//create your function, that runs on the cron you just made
function Your_Function() {
  echo 'Hi its 15 minuts';
}
```

I did not made this, the credits goes to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179694/wp-schedule-event-every-day-at-specific-time . Hope it helps some one!

EDIT: if you install a plugin, you can see your cron jobs with a gui, i have wp-control. can check crons at `yourdomain/wp-admin/tools.php?page=crontrol_admin_manage_page`

Comment: I'm new to Wordpress development. 'Your_Function_Hook' is supposed to be a hook that already exists on Worpress, like 'admin_menu' or something alike? Or am I creating a hook in this case? I mean, what will trigger the schedule?